# problems installing gdal module on ubuntu python version 3.10.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gdal

I had installed gdal on ubuntu for python version 3.10.6 using pip3 install.  Unfortunately when I attempt to run a program with the following line:

```
import gdal
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/jason/test.py", line 1, in <module>
 import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError:  No module named 'gdal'
```

I had attempted to reinstall gdal using pip3 and get the following message:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packaages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.4.3)

What can I do to ensure a successful installation of the gdal module?  How to I install gdal using sudo apt-get install?  When I tried this I get a message:

```
E: Unable to locate package gdal
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you already have a system-install GDAL 3.4.3 that you cannot replace because you lack super-user privileges.

This you can check by typing `pip show gdal`.

If you want to import it in Python, the correct statement is:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have correctly installed GDAL binaries?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
```

Are you able to check GDAL version?

```
gdalinfo --version
```

If the answers are yes then executing following code should return something like `GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27`

```
python3 -c 'from osgeo import gdal; print(gdal.VersionInfo("–version"))'
```

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS*

Answer (score 0):

please avoid installing gdal with pip unless you create its own environment and have tried other methods (like with the anaconda prompt and using conda install and conda c-forge).

Follow the steps here at: https://youtu.be/Ul79ihg41Rs?si=YivM0049mFLTlWrO

This step-by-step solution got gdal working for me after I tried all the simple solutions in my console and even conda. I'd recommend uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda if you have it, then downloading VS's newer build tools at: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ as you need these to build the wheels for GDAL.

Then you can start by attempting "conda install gdal".
If that doesn't work, start a new environment, activate it, and use c-forge to install.
If this doesn't work, then a new environment can be set ending with python=3 to attempt pip install, but this is last resort. ALL the code is found at the youtube link. Good lucK!

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it's best to include the relevant information in case it ever goes down.