# Import error in conda environment for GDAL

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, miniconda, gdal-python-bindings

I am trying to install GDAL==2.2.2 in a conda environment. But I get the following error for some reason:

```
from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hug180/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/hug180/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/hug180/miniconda3/envs/awra_test/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/hug180/miniconda3/envs/awra_test/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libimf seems to be math library for intel compilers. I don't understand this error. No where in /usr/lib or any conda environment lib directories can I find libimf.so.

Comment: There's not a not a lot to go off, but my guess it that you used pip to install gdal rather than conda. If that is the case, I suggest you remove your .local/lib and use conda to install.

Answer (score 0):

Check if GDAL is properly installed in your conda environment. For that use `gdalinfo --version` command:

```
kuba@szostak:~$ conda activate
(base) kuba@szostak:~$ gdalinfo --version
```

If you see something like `GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02`, then everything seems to be fine. More details will be needed to solve your issue.

If you see `Command 'gdalinfo' not found`, then it seems that you have GDAL python bindings installed, but not GDAL binaries. In that case follow steps in these answers:

- [problems installing gdal module on ubuntu python version 3.10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76862564/2524798)
- [How can i install gdal for python in windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053127/2524798)